# Awk getting results back with multiple columns

Tags: linux, scripting, awk

I have a function that searches one column for one string, how would I allow it so I can provide my script with multiple columns to search with multiple search strings?

```
awk -v s=$1 -v c=$2 '$c ~ s { print $0 }' $3
```

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [Awk Search file for string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406735/awk-search-file-for-string) - You should have edited the linked question to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an or clause in the pattern:

```
awk -v s=$1 -v c=$2 '$c ~ s || $3 == "foo"' $3
```

will print all lines in the file $3 in which column $2 matches the string $1 or $3 matches the string "foo".  Note that the action "print $0" is redundant, and is the default if no action is given.